# Why do custom subclasses of BaseAdapters only require implementations of some abstract methods from the Adapter interface?

Tags: java, android, oop, adapter, baseadapter

I have extended the BaseAdapter and ArrayAdapter classes many times before, but I've always had one nagging question about the BaseAdapter: why does the absence of some methods from the 
android.widget.Adapter interface such as getView (common sense of course would say that you need this) cause compiler errors, while others, like hasStableIds do not cause any such errors? I know that BaseAdapter inherits these methods from ListAdapter, which inherits them from Adapter, but why would only a couple need to be implemented while others do not? The android documentation does not include those calls specifically in BaseAdapter documentation, so where is any indication for the need for those specific calls for an extension of BaseAdapter if only some need implementation? I know that I'm missing something, either in my understanding of oop principles or my abilities to read documentation. Thanks for the insights!

Note: the compiler error is:

```
MyAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method getItemId(int) in Adapter
```

The required methods that I have found are: getItem, getCount, getItemId, and getView

Second note: these are all abstract methods in Adapter, and ListAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does the absence of some methods from the android.widget.Adapter interface such as getView (common sense of course would say that you need this) cause compiler errors

Because `BaseAdapter` is an abstract class, and `getView()` is an abstract method.

> while others, like hasStableIds do not cause any such errors?

Because `BaseAdapter` has an implementation of `hasStableIds()` that subclasses can use if desired.

> The android documentation does not include those calls specifically in BaseAdapter documentation

You will find them in the inherited methods from `Adapter` section of the `BaseAdapter` documentation.

> so where is any indication for the need for those specific calls for an extension of BaseAdapter if only some need implementation?

Methods defined on `Adapter` and `ListAdapter`, that `BaseAdapter` does not implement, are required.

Methods defined on `Adapter` and `ListAdapter`, that `BaseAdapter` *does* implement, are not required, but can still be overridden if needed.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I feel quite silly now, as I managed to miss the hasStableIds call (and the others implemented) in the docs for BaseAdapter. Real facepalm moment. Thanks for clearing that up for me!